# Starting procrob_functional with a launchfile

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,
i'm trying to launch the procrob_funtional face recognition tool via launchfile. By starting the Fserver via rosrun you have to go to the directory in which the "facedata.xml" etc. are stored. How can I realize that in a launchfile?
I'm using ros groovy and the following code:

```
<launch>
  <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="Fserver" pkg="face_recognition" type="Fserver" output="screen"> 
    <param name="haarcascade_frontalface_alt" value="$(find face_recognition)/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"/>
    <param name="facedata" value="$(find face_recognition)/facedata.xml"/>
    <param name="train" value="$(find face_recognition)/train.txt"/>
  </node>
  <node name="Fclient" pkg="face_recognition" type="Fclient" output="screen">
  </node>
</launch>
```

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55760/starting-procrob_functional-with-a-launchfile/) by [Bison](https://answers.ros.org/users/4239/bison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use the 'cwd' attribute in your launch file. E.g.

This sets the working directory to the directory where the executable is placed. In this case, then you just need to put all required input files ( haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml, train.txt, facedata.xml  and the data folder) in the bin folder of the face_recognition package.

---

Originally posted by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) with karma: 143 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bison](https://answers.ros.org/users/4239/bison/) on 2013-06-20**:
Hi Pouyan, first of all, thanks for your answer. I tried the way you proposed, but when I enter the command for recognition nothing happens.

**Comment by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) on 2013-06-23**:
Hi Bison. Then the problem should be from somewhere else. Because if the working directory is not set correctly,  you get error like "can not find  haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" or so ..